# Django Migration from Github actions

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, google-cloud-sql

Hello I have a database in Google Cloud Platform and I am trying to figure out how to run a django migration from github actions once I have deployed my app to GCP's App engine.

I have tried using cloud_sql_proxy, but cannot get it to connect to my database. I would whitelist github actions ip address but I am not really sure what the ip addresses is either.

Here is the config I currently have:

```yaml
name: deploy-app-to-gcp
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main]
    paths:
      - '**'
jobs:
  migrate:
    name: Migrate Database
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: get env file
        run: echo "${{secrets.ENV_FILE}}" | base64 --decode > ./env_variables.yaml
      - name: Set up Python 3.9
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.9
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Get Cloud SQL Proxy
        run: |
          wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
          chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
      - name: migrate Database
        env:
          DATABASE_CONNECTION_ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
        run: |
          pip install ruamel.yaml
          set -a; eval $(python -c 'from pathlib import Path;from ruamel.yaml import YAML; print( "".join( [f"{k}={v!r}\n" for k, v in YAML().load(Path("env_variables.yaml"))["env_variables"].items() if not k.__eq__("DATABASE_CONNECTION_ADDRESS")] ) )'); set +a
          ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=com-cjoshmartin:us-central1:cms-db=tcp:5432 &
          python manage.py migrate
          exit 0;
```

Comment: You can get the list of IPs of Github from there: https://api.github.com/meta, in your code are you specifying port `5432` or cloud proxy only not able to connect with instance ? any error or logs ?

Comment: @HarshManvar I am specifying the port to be 5432 and I am getting `psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
 Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?`

for the GitHub IPs would I have to whitelist all those ips myself?

Answer (score 2):

To make the Cloud SQL Proxy work from GitHub actions, you'll need some form of credentials present in the environment. See the [README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy#credentials) for details.

Another option would be to enable Workload Identity Federation and use the [auth](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth) action, although this approach requires a lot more setup.

Comment: thanks I got the cloud SQL proxy working by setting the path to the credentials file as you suggested!

Answer (score 2):

Based on @enocom's answer I was able to perform the migrations I wanted by using the Cloud SQL Proxy and setting the path to the credentials file.

Here is what I changed:

Saving the GCloud credentials to a json file

```yaml
#...
      - name: get env file
        run: |
          echo "${{secrets.ENV_FILE}}" | base64 --decode > ./env_variables.yaml
          echo "${{secrets.GCLOUD_GITHUB_CREDENTIALS}}" | base64 --decode > ./secrets.json

#...
```

using the cloud sql proxy with the secret file

```sh
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=com-cjoshmartin:us-central1:cms-db=tcp:5432 -credential_file secrets.json &
```